# How to create a file with hexadecimal information (as char) from a pointer in binary standard?

Tags: c++, binary, hex, type-conversion, file-writing

I'm trying to create a file that takes the binary entries from a pointer, but I'm having some problems with the conversion.

My function is that one:

`pSec` is pointing to the first address with the information that I want to write.

```
int StoreFile::setK(unsigned int Slot, void* pSec, unsigned int Len) {
    int Ret = 0;
    char tLen[sizeof(Len)];
    char cSec[Len*2], *Sec;

    static char FName[fs_PathMaxLg];
    snprintf(FName, sizeof(FName)-1, "%s/Store.INI", _Dir);

    static char Section[2][20];

    snprintf(Section[0], sizeof(Section[0])-1, "%lu_SIZE", Slot);
    snprintf(Section[1], sizeof(Section[1])-1, "%lu_DATA", Slot);

    do {
```

Here I try to check all addresses, passing the information to a `char*`, but I want that this information come as a hexadecimal (an array of `char` with hexadecimal contents), but I'm not having success in passing the information from the address pointed to a `char`.

```
        BYTE *ptr = (BYTE*)pSec;
        for (int i = 0; i != Len; i++) {
            Sec = strdup((const char*)ptr[i]);
            // snprintf(Sec, 2, "%2.2x", ptr[i]);
            // cSec = (char*)pSec;
            // pSec += 1;
            Sec += 2;
        }

        snprintf(tLen, sizeof(Len), "%x", Len);
```

Here is the other function that takes the array of chars to write into the file, the problem is only when writing `Sec`.

```
        Ret = WriteProfile(FName, "STOCK", Section[0], tLen);
        if (Ret != 1) {
            break;
        }
        Ret = WriteProfile(FName, "STOCK", Section[1], Sec);
        if (Ret != 1) {
            break;
        }
        Ret = 0;
    } while(0);
```

Have you any suggestions to improve this code?
I have tried a lot of things.

Comment: If pSec is not a zero terminated string, don't try to use it in strdup.

Answer (score 0):

So the central part is to convert binary data into hexademical representation.

Since one byte converts to two hex digits, one hex digit equals to 4 binary bits. So you have to convert the high 4 bits and low 4 bits of a byte respectively.

Suppose you want to convert `n` bytes from `data` into string `s`, you can do like this:

```
// convert lower 4 bit to hex
char byte2hex(char byte) {
    byte &= 0x0f;
    if (byte >= 10) {
        // a-f
        return byte + 'a' - 10;
    } else {
        // 0-9
        return byte + '0';
    }
}

string bin2hex(const char *data, int n) {
    string s;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        s.push_back(byte2hex(data[i]>>4));
        s.push_back(byte2hex(data[i]));
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Tnx, I have 2 questions: 1)How can I get the information [data] of one address? Am I doing right when scanning each address and converting each one separately? There are no easy way to do that?  2)I know that the definition of a string is an array of characters but I can use as the same thing? Because I can't change the entry of the other function (so :: string s == char *s in a function call) or I have to convert using strcpy(for exemple) ?

Comment: 1) You have to convert each byte separately. I use array to get the content of each byte: `data[i]`. 2) In C, a string is a null-terminated char array. But in C++, there is a type called `string`, which is `basic_string<char>` and is not a char array.